# Bash - variable contains dollar signs

Tags: bash, quoting, php

I have a php script that passes a variable to a bash script:

```
exec("bash.sh $path")
```

The bash script looks like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
path=$1

echo $path
```

If the path ends in dollar signs like so: `myfile.$$$`

The output is: `myfile.32577$`

How can I escape the dollars in the variable, so that the echo is accurate?

Answer (score 4):

PHP's `exec()` executes the command through a shell, so even before your script runs, there's a shell that processes the command line. `$$` in the shell is a special variable for the process id of the shell, but you'd get the same for anything else that looks like it could be a variable.

The [PHP manual for `exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) explicitly reminds to quote the command or the arguments for shell processing:

> **Warning**
>   When allowing user-supplied data to be passed to this function, use *escapeshellarg()* or *escapeshellcmd()* to ensure that users cannot trick the system into executing arbitrary commands.

I can't find a version of `system()`/`exec()`/others that would allow running a command directly (like the multi-argument version of `system()`/`exec()` in Perl), so it may be that the only option is to use [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php). It quotes the argument with single quotes and handles single quotes too.

```
$ php -r '$foo="$$$"; system("/bin/echo $foo");'
21836$

$ php -r '$foo="$$$"; system("/bin/echo " . escapeshellarg($foo));'
$$$
```

(You could use `escapeshellcmd()` to quote the whole script, but I'd avoid situations where that's required: the shell language is complex enough that there's a good chance the quoting will fail at some obscure case.)

---

Also, as Kusalananda mentions, (and as usual) you still want to quote the variables in your Bash script too. So use `echo "$path"` rather than `echo $path`. The dollar sign is not a problem here, whitespace and glob characters are.

See:

- [Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)  on Greg's wiki, and
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Comment: `$$` _would_ be an issue though ;-)

Comment: @Kusalananda, err, I may be missing the joke here. The `$$` won't be expanded from the contents of `$path`, quotes or not. E.g. with `foo=$$; echo $foo`, the problem is the assignment, not the expansion. Right..? (Of course if they literally write `$$` in their script, then that's their problem.)

Comment: Duh. Right you are. Also, send more coffee...

Comment: I'd have one sent to you, if SE implemented that feature.

Answer (score 0):

In case that this `exec` feature in php is implemented via `sh -c cmd`, you need to call:

```
 exec("bash.sh '$path'")
```

inside your shell script, there does not seem to be a problem, since `$$` would only be expanded if you did use `eval`.

Comment: Single-quoting's not good enough against hostile attempts.  For instance, anybody manages to set a filename to `myfile';rm -rf ~;'.$$$`, ...  You need to escape internal singlequotes with something like `sed -z "s,','\\\'',g;s,.*,'&',"`.